# Why does html tag take the background of the body tag only when the html tag has no background-color property set

Tags: html, css, background

So I noticed that when I remove the `background` or `background-color` property from the `html` selector when  there is a `background` or `background-color` property present for the `body` selector, the body's background takes up the entire screen.

However, when there is a `background` or `background-color` property set for the `html` tag then the body's `background` property only affects the portion of the screen the body takes up, AKA the content of the body takes up, and not the entire screen.

What is the reason for this (bug, decision...) and do I now have to set both the backgrounds for `html` and `body` now? Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide a demo?

Comment: @ChrisHappy See my answer for demos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.

According to the W3C [Colors and backgrounds](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/colors.html#background) page,

> For HTML documents, however, we recommend that authors specify the background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element. For documents whose root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML "html" element that has computed values of 'transparent' for 'background-color' and 'none' for 'background-image', user agents must instead use the computed value of the background properties from that element's first HTML "BODY" element or XHTML "body" element child when painting backgrounds for the canvas, and must not paint a background for that child element.

Or, tl;dr: Leaving the `<html>`'s background alone and only styling the body will cause the background to be assigned to the whole document. This is the recommendation.

The reason is, probably, for compatibility reasons. Long ago, the `<body>`, element also played the role of the canvas, and the `<html>` element did not really have any properties of its own. So you could assign a `bgcolor` property to the `<body>` (but not to the `<html>`) and that would become the canvas background.

And the answer to your last question is: only if you want to. In most cases, not styling the `<html>` at all will be enough. Except in special cases, e.g. if you want a differently coloured edge around the body, as you noticed.

Example with background on the `<body>` only:

```css
body {background:lime}
```

```html
Hello world
```

Example with different backgrounds for the `<html>` and the `<body>`:

```css
html {background:orange}
body {background:lime}
```

```html
Hello world
```